# trouble initializing Graph.new using ruby rdf.rb gem

Tags: ruby, rdf

I am trying to intitialize a graph following the documentation for the ruby RDF gem. (http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rdf/RDF/Graph)

Documentation provides the following example:

```
graph = Graph.new("http://rubygems.org/")
```

I've tried to run this exact command and I get an error (which I don't really understand). (Note that I have successful loaded a graph when using a file from my local machine, so I think there is some trouble with the attempt to load a graph from an http url.)

I'm running the command through the command line interface Gem Thor. Below is the executable file and then the error returned.

file `lbp`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rdf'
require 'rdf/rdfxml'
require 'rdf/ntriples'
require 'thor'
require 'pry'

class LbpCli < Thor 
  desc "hello", "say hello to NAME"
  def hello(name)
      puts "Hello #{name}!"
  end

  desc "init", "create projectifles dirs in current working directory"
  def init(dir="projectfiles")
      directories = ["#{dir}/Conf", "#{dir}/Textfiles", "#{dir}/citationlists"]
      FileUtils.mkpath(directories)
  end

  desc "projecfile", "make projetfile from SCTA" 
  def projectfile
      graph = RDF::Graph.new("http://rubygems.org")
  end
end

LbpCli.start(ARGV)
```

projectfile is the relevant method. Below is the command run and the error returned.

file `lbp` run with method `projectfile`

```
$ ./lbp projectfile
/Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/model/graph.rb:126:in `initialize': Can't apply context unless initialized with `data` supporting contexts (ArgumentError)
    from ./lbp:28:in `new'
    from ./lbp:28:in `projectfile'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from ./lbp:45:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT**

if I change the construction slightly by explicitly creating `resource` like so:

```
resource = RDF::Resource(RDF::URI.new("http://rdf.rubyforge.org/"))
graph = RDF::Graph.load(resource)
```

I get a new error:

```
bin $ ./lbp projectfile
/Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/util/file.rb:66:in `open_file': uninitialized constant RDF::Util::File::OpenSSL (NameError)
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/reader.rb:136:in `open'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/mixin/mutable.rb:43:in `load'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/model/graph.rb:81:in `block in load'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/model/graph.rb:131:in `call'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/model/graph.rb:131:in `initialize'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/model/graph.rb:80:in `new'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/rdf-1.1.7/lib/rdf/model/graph.rb:80:in `load'
    from ./lbp:29:in `projectfile'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lbp/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from ./lbp:47:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Documentation provides the following example:

```
graph = Graph.new("http://rubygems.org/")
```

Indeed, this is obsolete, and the documentation must be updated. The proper way to load a graph is the following:

```
graph = Graph.load("http://rubygems.org/")
```

although, this won't load any triples. You could try this:

```
graph = RDF::Graph.load("http://ruby-rdf.github.io/rdf/etc/doap.nt")
```

> if I change the construction slightly by explicitly creating resource like so:

```
resource = RDF::Resource(RDF::URI.new("http://rdf.rubyforge.org/"))
graph = RDF::Graph.load(resource)
```

Yes, no triples their either, and `RDF::Resource(RDF::URI.new(...))` is redundant, as an `RDF::URI` is a subclass of `RDF::Resource`. The load I showed previously should do the job.

The docs in the README (which you can find here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-rdf/rdf, along with other documentation) are a bit clearer. I made a pass over examples to make sure they worked with the 1.1 release, but obviously missed this one. I'll go through and re-check the examples and re-generate the docs.